# Excel Geography Can't Find Coordinates for Some Cities

Tags: microsoft-excel, coordinates

I followed the steps from this guide to [Find Latitude and Longitude for Each City in Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/find-latitude-and-longitude-for-each-city-in-excel/), through which Excel can give me the longitude and latitude info when I enter the name of a city.

When I tried *Manchester* or *Sheffield*, it worked. But when I entered *Bristol (England)*, it doesn't seem to work. With *Bristol, Tennessee* it works.

I was wondering why and how could I find the longitude and latitude for Bristol, UK?

Comment: My experimentation indicates some type of smart filling. So typing in `Bristol` might smart fill to `Bristol, Tennessee`. Typing `Bristol, UK` gets to what you want.

Comment: @gns100 Does it show on your side the latitude and longitude of Briston, UK?

Comment: @gns100 No, that doesn't work, it seems like Microsoft doesn't have the longitude and latitude info as well as the Admin Division 2 (County/district/other) info.

Comment: @JacktheRanger The geographic data type is powered by Bing.com. Thus, the data shown on your workbook/worsheet come directly from the search engine. If you click the icon next to Manchester or Sheffield, you will see that both latitude and longitude are present, but not for Bristol as bing as not reported. That's the reason they are not shown.

Comment: You may try the addin shown on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68368591

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't looked in full detail. I was going to say maybe a workaround was to go to wikipedia and add the coordinates, then it would flow through. But the coordinates are already there in wikipedia, so yes it is a mystery why Bing pulls in coordinates for others but not Bristol, UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The data available to extract with formulas are the field that are in the Geographic info card, and that card is a black box which pulls 'some' info from Bing that you can't really add to. So if the city/area's info box has the coordinates then you can get it in this way, and f not then not. And Bristol's doesn't have it.

[image]

---

As non-native alternative, you can try the well documented macros find in this repository https://github.com/gramener/geocode-excel

Which will use ***Nominatim*** (no key needed but not as good) or ***Google Maps*** (needs a key) APIs to pull in the Coordinates.
[image]